# localhost - can't connect

Tags: localhost, wamp

I installed a WAMP package on a Windows 7 machine and everything ( Apache, php, MySQL, phpMyAdmin) appear to have installed correctly.

However when I try to access localhost or phpMyAdmin via the browser, I get error `Server Not Found`.

I've tried using:

- http://localhost,
- http://localhost/phpmyadmin,
- http://127.0.0.1,
- http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin

In all cases I get the same error.

I've checked the httpd file it says `Listen 80`.

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` says `127.0.0.1 localhost`.

The apache log says :

```
[Sun Mar 04 16:07:51 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Sun Mar 04 16:07:51 2012] [notice] Server built: Jan 28 2012 11:16:39

[Sun Mar 04 16:07:51 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2636

[Sun Mar 04 16:07:51 2012] [notice] Child 2636: Child process is running

[Sun Mar 04 16:07:51 2012] [notice] Child 2636: Acquired the start mutex.

[Sun Mar 04 16:07:51 2012] [notice] Child 2636: Starting 64 worker threads.

[Sun Mar 04 16:07:51 2012] [notice] Child 2636: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

Anything else I should try?

Comment: Do you have any other servers running like IIS7? Have you tried to configure wamp to start on a different port than 80?

Comment: @cale_b: you didn't read completely. He mentioned the appropriate part of his hosts file. It's there. He had also mentioned that he had tried http://127.0.0.1.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with 5.3.10 and WAMP, but if I switch to 5.3.0 or (install and) switch to 5.3.1 it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you dont have anything else running on port 80.  Skype for instance listens on port 80 and 443 by default so they conflict for me.  If you're also running skype go to options and Connection > Advanced to disable it using port 80 and 443.

Comment: Thans but skype isn[t running.